# USB-stick Error "Can’t mount file" "The path is not mounted."

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

I have Lubuntu 20.04 installed and am unable to add any files on a USB-stick after using it to install this OS, so I tried to delete files and to erase the partitions on it.

When I try to open it, the following messages appear:
*"Error"   "Can’t mount file"   "The path is not mounted."*

When I select this stick on gparted, it shows being "unallocated".

Many thanks in advance for any hints to solve this issue.

manoka

Comment: You need to create a partition on the USB. If the drive is showing as "unallocated", you need to format a new partition in either `ext4` or `NTFS` or something else that UNIX can read in order to put new files on the drive.

Comment: Most methods to write an ISO to a thumb-drive (for *live* use including installation) is written as a RO (read-only) image, meaning it's a closed system and cannot be changed. This is beneficial for security reasons.  You need to re-format (create a new partition table) on the device to use it, unless you prepared it for persistence use.  Why use `gparted` as Lubuntu (being Qt based; ie. LXQt) uses KDE Partition Manager which is the same tool but more resource (esp. ram) efficient https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.7/kde_partitionmanager.html

Comment: After creating a partition I tried to copy a file on to the stick, but am unable to do so, and I get the following message: "Error opening file “....zip”: Permission denied".

Comment: Now I managed to copy a file to the stick after I formatted it to a fat32 file system instead of ext4.

Answer (score 1):

Now I managed to copy a file to the stick after I formatted it to a fat32 file system instead of ext4.